# Didn't find class on path: DexPathList on Android Library

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, aar

I'm working on an Android Library to module some work on my app and I use retrofit to consume some web APIs.

When I compile and use it in my sample app (compiling the library module) in the same Android Studio project everything works fine, but when I use the library from the artifact I got the error `Didn't find class on Path....`

My gradle.build file contains this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3"
    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3"
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
}
```

I've tried with retrofit and retrofit2 but I still got the same crash on my app implementing the library

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_471cb7629dd1bd2eaf19897f0bfa2e292d59a1a2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mx.segundamano.android-payments-library-0.1-SNAPSHOT_afd67b66a26310987e26f412f53082c415795025-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.3.0_ffb5ab0b136af54fef26d794f3208310ca6ef941-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.3.0_2834a08897c09d9f4cf6a603048125bd86044324-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.3.0_0fe06b17a4b2ae866e5066f3ea5bc8d596bd609e-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-multidex-1.0.1_9e5a739896463403b4d643ff254bf74dcc98371f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.3.0_eba794855dfef17238864c6651afded84f82cf47-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0_41e987bda5b0c3ecdbb65ba4dfa7c24496152077-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/mx.segundamano.paymentsdemo-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

05-11 11:40:03.737  4279  4279 E AndroidRuntime:    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.j

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: Actually the problem it wasn't it the app, it was in the library, at the moment when you publish your library in the artifact, you need to set the publish to contain also the dependencies in the artifactory, in that way when you add your library as a dependency of your app, you'll have all the library's dependencies with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem!

My problem it wasn't in the app, it was in my library, I set wrong the publish task in my gradle file. This is how you should do it for Bintray.

```
task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives generateSourcesJar
}

bintray {
    ...
    configurations = ['archives']
}
```

Check in your artifactory framework how you should add dependencies to your library.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a simple android studio problem rearrange the imports to be in the correct order just in case and then Clean and build your project.

That solved the issue for me

Comment: Actually I said that as superstition you know things that you do for no reason. So I really don't thing  but there you go: 


 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'

Try cleaning the project 
building
and if that didn't work restart AndroidStudio
also sometimes you need to restart your Computer 
because sometimes ADB fails
and it keeps running new adb.exe

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also faced the same problem. When I went through the documentation provided by  Github I cam accroosed due to some changes you will be facing this error. This error is likely to encountered if you are using retrofit version **2.7.0** (As in my case, I am also using the version of retrofit. So to resolve the issue I did the below steps:

1. I added Java version 8 support enable in my android project
   To add Java version 8 support. open Gradle file of project level and inside android 
   bracket add below code.

   ```
   android {

   compileOptions {
       sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
   }
   ```
2. And in the same gradle file add below mentioned dependency as well

   ```
   implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1"
   ```

Why to do mentioned changes is briefly mentioned in the below link

[Clik to find more details of additional informatio](https://cashapp.github.io/2019-02-05/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5)

Hope this will help and save some time.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    
    }
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.